# Replace cells with a matching ID in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, match, matching

I have data in the form:

```
Input_SNP       Set_1     Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5    Set_6     Set_7
rs70812    4:12309   7:189029   2:2134   17:43232  12:51123  11:15123  19:4312
rs34812    5:61233   2:571022  1:57012   3:537012  14:57123  4:57129   1:61507
rs15602    1:571209  12:34120  9:41236   12:32417  3:57120   9:34123   3:41235
rs90143    7:83541   9:659123  5:23412   16:98234  18:472351 20:12357  1:13421
rs70823    14:89023  13:42081  8:32098   5:431332  9:234134  13:7831   2:74012
rs100980   11:51003  1:100098  10:409123 12:412309 13:34123  16:431098 3:58023
rs10341    18:90312  15:609123 1:70923   2:102358  5:019824  17:120394 9:80123
```

I actually have 10,000 Sets and about 4,000 rows. But this is a good sample. I also have a file that is:

```
set snpID     rsMatch
1   4:12309   rs241984
2   7:189029  rs104141
3   2:2134    rs485506
4   17:43232  rs345180
5   12:51123  rs129819
6   11:15123  rs757492
7   19:4312   rs711403
1   5:61233   rs341098
2   2:571022  rs512309
3   1:57012   rs120394
4   3:537012  rs510293
5   14:571234 rs234098
6   4:57129   rs71302
7   1:61507   rs234109
1   1:571209  rs09384
... ...       ...
```

I would like to replace the number format of my Set_1, Set_2, Set_3, etc. to its rsMatch format like this:

```
    Input_SNP  Set_1     Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5     Set_6     Set_7
    rs70812    rs241984 rs104141 rs485506 rs345180 rs129819 rs757492 rs711403
    rs34812    rs341098 rs512309 rs120394 rs510293 rs234098 rs71302  rs234109
    rs15602    rs098384 ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
...        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
```

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to do this? I was thinking of R dataframes, but I'm open to anything...

Comment: Please do not [double post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712831/replace-cells-with-a-matching-id-in-r-dataframe)

Comment: I did not double post. Each of my posts contains a different second file to solve the issue of the first file. They are completely different ways to solve a question and I would like both answers to test computing speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem with a `merge` after appropriate transformations. I'm using `library(reshape2)` to get the data in the correct shape for merging and back for output.

```
#read in files
df1<-read.table("file1",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)   
df2<-read.table("file2",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(reshape2)
m1<-melt(df1,id.vars="Input_SNP")
m2<-transform(df2,variable=paste0("Set_",set),value=snpID)
m<-merge(m1,m2)
out<-dcast(m,Input_SNP~variable,value.var="rsMatch")

print(out)

  Input_SNP    Set_1    Set_2    Set_3    Set_4    Set_5    Set_6    Set_7
1   rs15602  rs09384     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
2   rs34812 rs341098 rs512309 rs120394 rs510293     <NA>  rs71302 rs234109
3   rs70812 rs241984 rs104141 rs485506 rs345180 rs129819 rs757492 rs711403
```

Comment: I tried this. Right after I enter the line `out <- dcast(m, Input_SNP~variable, value.var="rsMatch")` I got the message: `Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length` and then my output was a table full of cells with just the value `1`.

Comment: Sounds like your file has duplicates. Try `out<-dcast(m,Input_SNP~variable,function(x) x[1],value.var="rsMatch")` to select the first.

Comment: Awesome! It worked! How can I check to make sure that every single cell starts with rs now? If a row somehow didn't have a column with a matching rs value I would like to delete it

Comment: As in `na.omit(out)`?

Comment: Look at BondedDust's answer. See his output. what If I have a line like his number 3, where maybe a there wasn't a matching rsID for a corresponding numberID. I'm trying to get rid of rows that might look like his row 3.

Comment: The above uses NAs for missing values, so `na.omit(out)` will get rid of any rows with missing values...

Comment: That is weird. I wrote your output to a tsv txt file and opened it, and it looks good, except that some of the rsIDs didn't replace the numberID, could this be the duplicates? If so, how could that be avoided? If not, then how do I delete a row that has six out of the seven columns having the correct rsID but one column didn't match to a rsID

Answer (score 2):

You should work on a copy , but I'm living dangerously and worked on the original. First we need to match the values in the Set_n columns to the second input dataframe:

```
 sapply(inp1[-1], match, inp2$snpID)
     Set_1 Set_2 Set_3 Set_4 Set_5 Set_6 Set_7
[1,]     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
[2,]     8     9    10    11    NA    13    14
[3,]    15    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[4,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[5,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[6,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[7,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

You didn't give us all the needed values but the NA's will be needed as placeholders. Those values are index positions inot the second dataframe. Notice that it is transposed (which is easy enough to fix with `t()`:

The next step is to replace the items with their lookup values from the rsMatch column:

```
inp1[-1][] <- inp2$rsMatch[ t(sapply(inp1[-1], match, inp2$snpID)) ]
#----------------
> inp1
  Input_SNP    Set_1    Set_2   Set_3 Set_4 Set_5 Set_6 Set_7
1   rs70812 rs241984 rs341098 rs09384  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2   rs34812 rs104141 rs512309    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3   rs15602 rs485506 rs120394    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
4   rs90143 rs345180 rs510293    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
5   rs70823 rs129819     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
6  rs100980 rs757492  rs71302    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
7   rs10341 rs711403 rs234109    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Second attempt: The index could be: 'cbind( 1.1+(.9:nrow(inp2))%/%7, inp2$set+1)' which did succeed but the seq(.)-method illustrated is a bit more solid.

```
   out1 <- inp1; out1[ cbind( rep(1:(nrow(inp2)), length=nrow(inp2), each=7), inp2$set+1) ] <- inp2$rsMatch

> out1
  Input_SNP    Set_1     Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5     Set_6    Set_7
1   rs70812 rs241984  rs104141  rs485506  rs345180  rs129819  rs757492 rs711403
2   rs34812 rs341098  rs512309  rs120394  rs510293  rs234098   rs71302 rs234109
3   rs15602  rs09384  12:34120   9:41236  12:32417   3:57120   9:34123  3:41235
4   rs90143  7:83541  9:659123   5:23412  16:98234 18:472351  20:12357  1:13421
5   rs70823 14:89023  13:42081   8:32098  5:431332  9:234134   13:7831  2:74012
6  rs100980 11:51003  1:100098 10:409123 12:412309  13:34123 16:431098  3:58023
7   rs10341 18:90312 15:609123   1:70923  2:102358  5:019824 17:120394  9:80123
```

It didn't appear to me that the request actually used the Input_SNP values in the matching.

Comment: Very close, but I want the all the ones with set value 1 to be in column 1. And all the columns with set value 2 to be in column 2 etc. Do you notice the difference between our outputs ?

Comment: So you want to assign to the column determined by the set column?

Comment: The Input_SNP values are not used in the matching, you are correct. Your output now is what I want! Can you explain which steps you exactly used?

Comment: specifically, what does the 1.1 and .9 mean?

Comment: I needed to tweak the offsets because using integers was causing the modulo arithmetic to cycle back at the wrong point in the sequence. I probably should have used `seq(1,7, length-nrow(inp2) )` now that I think about it again.

Comment: So what is the total "script" from start to end then? You have the right output, I want to give you the chosen answer!

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me in advance but I see both an Excel and SQL solution here as you are relating two distinct pieces of datasets (i.e., database tables, worksheets). Both solutions can still be integrated as data preparation prior to importing into R. This may be more for future readers than the OP.

**Excel Solution**

Simple `VLookup` or `Index/Match` (see both examples using worksheets named RsmatchWide, RsmatchLong). `IFERROR()` is used to remove the `#NA`.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(RsmatchLong!$C$2:$C$16, 
         MATCH(RsmatchWide!B2,RsmatchLong!$B$2:$B$16, FALSE)), "")

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RsmatchWide!B2,RsmatchLong!$B$2:$C$16,2,FALSE),"")
```

[image: RsMatch in Excel]

Once prepared, save worksheet as csv then import into R:

```
df <- read.csv("C:/Path/To/RsMatchDataset.csv")
```

**SQL Solution**

Run a select query with individual subqueries for each set (example below used MS Access but should work with any SQL dialect including SQLite, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.):

```
SELECT rFinal.Input_SNP,

  (SELECT RsmatchLong.rsMatch
   FROM RsmatchLong INNER JOIN RsmatchWide r1 ON RsmatchLong.snpID = r1.Set_1
   WHERE r1.Input_SNP = rFinal.Input_SNP) As Set_1,

  (SELECT RsmatchLong.rsMatch
   FROM RsmatchLong INNER JOIN RsmatchWide r2 ON RsmatchLong.snpID = r2.Set_2
   WHERE r2.Input_SNP = rFinal.Input_SNP) As Set_2,

  (SELECT RsmatchLong.rsMatch
   FROM RsmatchLong INNER JOIN RsmatchWide r3 ON RsmatchLong.snpID = r3.Set_3
   WHERE r3.Input_SNP = rFinal.Input_SNP) As Set_3,

  (SELECT RsmatchLong.rsMatch
   FROM RsmatchLong INNER JOIN RsmatchWide r4 ON RsmatchLong.snpID = r4.Set_4
   WHERE r4.Input_SNP = rFinal.Input_SNP) As Set_4,

  (SELECT RsmatchLong.rsMatch
   FROM RsmatchLong INNER JOIN RsmatchWide r5 ON RsmatchLong.snpID = r5.Set_5
   WHERE r5.Input_SNP = rFinal.Input_SNP) As Set_5,

  (SELECT RsmatchLong.rsMatch
   FROM RsmatchLong INNER JOIN RsmatchWide r6 ON RsmatchLong.snpID = r6.Set_6
   WHERE r6.Input_SNP = rFinal.Input_SNP) As Set_6,

  (SELECT RsmatchLong.rsMatch
   FROM RsmatchLong INNER JOIN RsmatchWide r7 ON RsmatchLong.snpID = r7.Set_7
   WHERE r7.Input_SNP = rFinal.Input_SNP) As Set_7

FROM RsMatchWide rFinal
```

[image: RsMatch in SQL]

Even R can create the underlying tables, then run the query with RODBC:

```
library(RODBC) 

conn <-odbcDriverConnect('driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
                          DBQ=C:\\PathTo\\Database.accdb')

# SAVING DATA FRAMES AS NEW DB TABLES
sqlSave(conn, RsMatchWide, append=FALSE, rownames=TRUE)
sqlSave(conn, RsMatchLong, append=FALSE, rownames=TRUE)

# CREATING DATA FRAME FROM QUERY, 
# QUERY STRING, strSQL, WILL BE SQL SELECT STATEMENT ABOVE
newdf <- sqlQuery(conn, strSQL)

close(conn)
```

The only challenge I foresee above is scaling this out to your 10,000 sets. Excel has a column limit as do various SQL Databases. Consider breaking apart and merging in R.

Comment: Looks like excel can take ~16,000 columns. I'll try that solution first and report back

Comment: Where do I type that command in Excel? and are these different sheets?

Comment: Command is a formula to be placed in formula bar, then dragged over the other cells, `$` locks various references. Yes, as I mentioned and shown in screenshots, example uses three different sheets of one workbook: `Rsmatchwide`, `Rsmatchlong`, `Rsmatchfinal`.

Comment: I tried this, and it did not work. I got #NAME? I think because it's not calculating a table, it seems to just be calculating for a single cell. Thoughts?

Comment: Correct that is a cell formula as it indexes/matches on cell values. Use it first in `B2` then drag across and down to apply to other cells.

Comment: I tried this `=IFERROR(INDEX(sheet2!$D$2:$D$170901, MATCH(sheet1!B2,sheet2!$C$2:$C$170901, FALSE)), "")`, because my sheets are named `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`, and my columns in sheet2 are moved over 1 to the right. But I didn't get an output. It just remains as the string of code when I hit enter

Comment: Because no qualifying data exists since you moved over one to the right. Adjust formula for `Sheet2` location (Ds to Es, and Cs to Ds): `=IFERROR(INDEX(sheet2!$E$2:$E$170901, MATCH(sheet1!B2,sheet2!$D$2:$D$170901, FALSE)), "")`

Comment: No I did that, you originally had C's and B's so I switched them to D's and C's. Right?

Comment: I think I know what the problem is: I am using Libre Calc instead of Microsoft Excel, do you know the commands for that?

Comment: I have edited with the equivalent `VlookUp()` formula which is a [function in LibreCalc](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP). Adjust to its syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table v1.9.5` - installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
setDT(dt)
setDT(key)
ids  = seq_len(7L) # or 10000L in your case
cols = paste("Set", ids, sep="_")
on   = "snpID"
for (i in ids) {
    names(on) = cols[i]
    dt[key[set == i], cols[i] := rsMatch, on = on]
}
dt[]
```

`key[set == i]` subsetting should be very fast as it uses binary search by *auto indexing* on `set` column. For each subset, corresponding to `i`, we join `snpID` from the subset'd data.table with `dt` on the corresponding `Set*` column, and update (`cols[i] := rsMatch`) the corresponding column  by reference with the column `rsMatch`.

This should be both fast and memory efficient.

Comment: I'm using R 3.1, and it says that devtools is not available for that version, what version did you use?